# Guest wireless. HP to Cisco VLANs

Tags: wifi, vlan, static-routes

I'm having trouble getting guest Internet access working. I have HP V-M200 WAPs and a Cisco RV042G for internet and a HP 1910 switch in the middle.

I created a second Wireless Community/SSID on the HP WAPs using VLAN2. I tagged the port going to my DHCP server with VLAN 2 and set up DHCP relay in the 1910 and I'm able to get an address from the DHCP server in my new Guest scope. But I can't ping anything past the VLAN2 interface address on the 1910.

The Cisco says it can do VLANs1-4 and has 4 LAN ports. It also has a "multiple subnet" option which I tried using, but  I wasn't able to ping the secondary address I created from the guest subnet. But from some reason I can ping it from the main subnet on VLAN 1. I set LAN port 2 on the Cisco to VLAN 2.

Is it possible to make this work with the hardware I have? Do I just need to set up a route on the switch? What kind of VLAN setting should be on the port going to Cisco port 2? (tagged 2, untagged 2,.. PVID?)

For the sake of typing examples, the main, existing subnet is 192.168.1.0/24 and the guest network I'm trying to make is on 192.168.100.0/24